# TTTAttributedLabel sizetofit and sizeWithFont is different

Tags: ios, uilabel, sizetofit, sizewithfont, tttattributedlabel

I am using TTTAttributedLabel and I usually use sizetofit in my tableview cell. After that, I use sizeWithFont in my cell height calculation. I set TTTAttributedLabel like this.

```
[self.attributedLabel setText:@"Test\n\n\n\n"];
CGSize contentSize = [self.attributedLabel.text sizeWithFont:self.attributedLabel.font
                                      constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.attributedLabel.frame), 1000)
                                          lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

[self.attributedLabel sizeToFit];
```

I notice that height is different. I got my output like this. So I guess it is wrong. May I know how to fix? I am testing on iOS 8 device.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should calculate sizing instead with `TTTAttributedLabel`'s built-in method

[`+[TTTAttributedLabel sizeThatFitsAttributedString:                    withConstraints:limitedToNumberOfLines:`](https://github.com/TTTAttributedLabel/TTTAttributedLabel/blob/1.13.3/TTTAttributedLabel/TTTAttributedLabel.h#L277-L288), which will return a proper `CGSize` for you.